# MS Graph API Calendar Update fails

Tags: c#, api, office365

Using Graph API to update calendar that I have created using the API previously gets the following error:
Your request can't be completed. The default calendar cannot be renamed.
Code: graphClient.Users[UserPrincipalName].Calendar.Request().UpdateAsync(calendar);

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com//tour) and visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com//help). You might also want to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com//questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I could update calendar name from my side. Please seen the screenshot below:
[image]

I think it could be you didn’t set up the correct permissions.
For necessary permissions you have to set up, please read from official docs from Microsoft. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-update?view=graph-rest-1.0

It also cloud be a bug for graph API SDK.

I’d recommend you check your permission first, if the permission is correct, than use c# to create HTTP request rather than use graph SDK